# "Malformed UTF-8 characters" error when trying to json_encode and array that holds some encrypted values

Tags: php, encryption, public-key-encryption, pki

I need to send some JSON data to an API endpoint that requires parts of the request to be encrypted. I have a public key that was supplied to me by the API provider. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```php
$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

openssl_public_encrypt('my_username', $username, openssl_pkey_get_public($key));
openssl_public_encrypt('my_pa55w0rd', $password, openssl_pkey_get_public($key));

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$result = $client->post(
    'https://api.domain.com/endpoint',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $bearerToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'json' => [
            'username' => $username,
            'pasword' => $password,
            'unencrypted_key' => 'an unencrypted value,
        ]
    ]
);
```

The code snippet above gives me an `json_encode error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` error. When doing a `echo $username;` I see that the string outputted has a bunch of malformed characters:
[image: malformed encrypted string]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there's some other approach I should take to encrypting the values before it gets json encoded.

**NOTE:** Although I am not using the `json_encode` function in my code above, I believe the guzzle HTTP library `json_encode`s the array before sending out the request.

Comment: `openssl_public_encrypt` returns a binary stream, that's the mangled output, you would need to encode it in ascii first, probably with `base64_encode` but why do you need encryption if the transport is already using ssl ? Check with the api provider.

Comment: @msg thanks for the reply. This is the design choice of the API provider. I've tried `base64_encode`ing the output of `openssl_public_encrypt` but that output doesn't get recognized by the API provider as encrypted. The API provider has a tool for RSA encryption here: https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/utility/encrypt.html using the output of that tool as the encrypted value does work.

Comment: Their utility is hex-encoding the data instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [msg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4782169/msg) noted in a comment:

> `openssl_public_encrypt` returns a binary stream, that's the mangled output, you would need to encode it in ascii first, probably with `base64_encode` but why do you need encryption if the transport is already using ssl ? Check with the api provider.

However, it's also possible that they're expecting hex-encoded data instead. Give `bin2hex()` a try instead.

If they have some other weird format (Base32Hex?), feel free to use [this RFC 4648 library](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding) to encode your messages.

---

### Important Security Information

This isn't an answer to your question, but it is something you and your API should both be aware of.

`openssl_public_encrypt` defaults to RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, which is vulnerable to [a padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5).

At a minimum: The developer for the API you're communicating with should stop accepting data encrypted with RSA with PKCS#1v1.5 padding and instead only accept OAEP ciphertexts.

There *are* [ways to work around Bleichenbacher's 1998 attack](https://paragonie.com/blog/2018/04/protecting-rsa-based-protocols-against-adaptive-chosen-ciphertext-attacks) but they're messy and can only be solved at a protocol level, not a the library or primitive level.

However, RSA encryption is messy for other reasons: [You can't encrypt large messages directly with RSA](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/12/everything-you-know-about-public-key-encryption-in-php-is-wrong#rsa-ecb).

There are also [plenty of other ways RSA can go wrong](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059600123/saltstack-rsa-e-d-1).

#### Recommendation

A better solution is to stop using RSA entirely.

Libsodium [has bindings in most popular programming languages](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages) (and is included in the PHP 7.2 core) and [makes this easier to get right](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use#crypto-box-seal).

```
// On your end...
$sendToProvider = sodium_bin2hex(
    sodium_crypto_box_seal($privateData, $publicKey)
);

// On their end...
$decrypted = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(
    sodium_hex2bin($encrypted),
    $keypair
);
```

You would have encountered the encoding issue either way (since both APIs return raw binary strings). However, using libsodium would have side-stepped a ton of security issues you probably weren't aware of until you read this StackOverflow answer.

Also: Don't feel bad if you didn't know. You're not alone. Even Zend Framework's cryptography library [got bit by these RSA vulnerabilities](https://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2015-10), and they had Enrico Zimuel on their team. RSA is just a bad choice for real world cryptography.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Scott. `bin2hex()` solved the issue for me! As for the subpar encryption techniques: I doubt this particular API provider will listen o any of this judging on their documentation, amount of time it takes for them to get back to a simple support ticket, and their overall developer environment. I'll pass it on tough, and thanks for a very helpful answer 